# Subtable type stucture in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if it is possible to have the following database behaviour:

1. Create a USER table, with primary key USER_ID
2. Data comes in from external source: e.g. "USER_ID, TIMESTAMP, DATA"
3. For each user in the USER table, create a table to store only data entries pertinent to USER_ID, and store all incoming Data with the correct USER_ID into that table
4. When querying all the data entries for a specific USER_ID, just return all rows from that table.

I could of course do this all in one table "ALLDATALOG" and then search for all entries in ALLDATALOG that contain USER_ID, but my concern is that as the ALLDATALOG table grows, searches will take too long.

Comment: Are you using any scripting language?

Comment: I will be using PHP as the scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You should not split your tables like that. You will want an index on the USER_ID column in your data log table. Searches do become slower as data size increases, but your strategy will not necessarily mitigate that. It will however make your application more complex to write, harder to debug, and quite likely actually slow it down.

You should also consider unpacking that data blob into additional columns and tables as appropriate in order to take advantage of the relational nature of the database.

How many rows do you expect the table to hold over time? Thousands? Millions? Billions? At what rate do you expect rows to be added?

Comment: It won't be an issue for the prototype that I am working on, but if it should be commercialised, then there might be say a few thousand  updates to the table per day from a few thousand USER_IDs. I just want to ensure that the solution is scalable right from the start.

Comment: I don't really have a good solution for scaling to millions of inserts per day (assuming you mean thousands of inserts for each of thousands of users per day), but I do know that having those thousands of tables will make your DB's query cache cry (and possibly other parts -- I doubt most RDBMS software is really designed for thousands of dynamically created tables)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1: As answered by Jonathan, do not split the tables. It won't help you increase the speed.

Suggestion 2: If you still want to split the tables. Use the logic in your PHP code. Check if the table for a particular use already exists or not. If it does, insert values in it and if it doesn't create a new one. Should be quite straight forward. If you want me to share code for this, let me know.